# recalculating probability in markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Each node can have three options. The likelihood of a specific option being chosen depends on how many times it was inserted.

For example, this is a table showing the location of each insertion and the resulting probability:

```
| Num Insertions at cell | Probabilities    | Total num insertions |
| ---------------------- | ---------------- | -------------------- |
| 0, 0, 0                | 0.0,  0.0,  0.0  | 0                    |
| 1, 0, 0                | 1.0,  0.0,  0.0  | 1                    |
| 1, 1, 0                | 0.5,  0.5,  0.0  | 2                    |
| 1, 1, 1                | 0.33, 0.33, 0.33 | 3                    |
| 2, 1, 1                | 0.5,  0.25, 0.25 | 4                    |
| 3, 1, 1                | 0.6,  0.2,  0.2  | 5                    |
```

I'm trying to work out the formula to *remove* a insertion and re-calculate the probabilities of the resulting row.

I figured out how to add an insertion: I first increment the total number of insertions, then define `n` as `1/total_num_insertions`. I multiply each probability in the row by `n` and then add `n` to the cell where the insertion took place at.

I'm not seeing how to do this in terms of removing a cell at a location.

I realize that since I am storing the num insertions at each cell than I can re-calculate them that way - each probability is `num_insertions_at_cell * (1/total_num_insertions)`. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it using only `total_num_insertions` and not `num_insertions_at_cell`, like was possible in the insertion case.

In other words, given `total_num_insertions = 5` and `probabilities = 0.6, 0.2, 0.2`, is there a way I can translate the command "remove 1 from the first cell" into `0.5, 0.25, 0.25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just undo the steps you took to add an insertion, one at a time:

1. Writing $T$ for `total_num_insertions`, subtract $\frac1T$ from the probability of the option you're looking at. For example, this turns $(0.6, 0.2, 0.2)$ into $(0.4, 0.2, 0.2)$.
2. Now the ratios between the probabilities are correct but the probabilities  sum up to $\frac{T-1}{T}$ instead of $1$. So we multiply each probability by $\frac{T}{T-1}$. For example, this turns $(0.4, 0.2, 0.2)$ into $(0.5, 0.25, 0.25)$ since we multiply by $\frac 54$.
3. Finally, subtract $1$ from `total_num_insertions`.

Comment: It turns out my approach for inserting was only working for the first three rounds (when the total number of insertions is <= 2).

Comment: That's probably because of something which I thought was a typo in your approach and now I think is a mistake. When you define $n$ to be the reciprocal of `total_num_insertions`, you should be multiplying by $1-n$, not by $n$. (For example, when adding a $5^{\text{th}}$ insertion, you should multiply every number by $\frac45$ before you add $\frac15$ in one position.)